# Installation failure of Impresspages on Two Servers

Tags: impresspages

I have tried installing Impresspages on my local xampp server, and was successful, but have JS errors and am unable to edit any content on front end.  I get the below error in my inspector.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouse' of undefined localhost/Ip/Internal/Content/assets/management.min.js?1:71

Does anyone know what is causing this?

I then tried to install it on my Cloudserver which runs WHM/Cpanel.  I was not able to install at all..  I get the below error:

[03-Jul-2014 19:25:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

What is causing this?  How can I fix?

Thanks in advance!!

Michael

http://www.digitalworkhorse.com/

Answer (score 0):

First issue shouldn't make any problems with content management. Refresh page, clear browser cache. Content management should work.

The second has nothing to do with ImpressPages. It's your servers problem with PHP installation.